# Whet does it means to append a integer to a list in erlang?

Tags: erlang

The normal way to do a list appending is via:

```
10> [1,2,3] ++ [4].
[1,2,3,4]
```

But after I convert it to the following way, I actually don't get the point what does the result means here:

```
11> [1,2, 3] ++ 4.  
[1,2,3|4]
```

Could anyone give me a explanation? Many thanks.

Comment: The use of `++` as means to append a value at the tail of a list is actually not the "normal" way. `++` has high runtime-costs if the left-hand side operand is a big list. The "normal" way is to accumulate head-first `[Head | Rest]`, and reverse later.

Comment: Yeah, I know it's much better to use head-first semantics. But I just wanna figure out what `[1,2,3|4]` means in Erlang. @maze-le

Comment: I would like to know that too, since I always had the assumption that, if you have the expression  `[Head|Rest]`, `Rest` must be a list... Which, clearly is not the case with your example (`Rest` seems to be the integer 4)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Erlang lists are described in [Getting Started with Erlang User's Guide](http://www.erlang.org/doc/getting_started/users_guide.html) in chapter [Sequential Programming](http://www.erlang.org/doc/getting_started/seq_prog.html) and subchapter [Lists](http://www.erlang.org/doc/getting_started/seq_prog.html#id61746). The operator `|` separates a head of the list from a tail. The proper list ends with the empty list. The syntax with `,` is just syntactic sugar.

```
1> [1|[2|[3|[]]]].
[1,2,3]
```

It is like `CONS` function in Lisp. The list is called improper list if doesn't end with the empty list.

```
2> [1|[2|[3|4]]]. 
[1,2,3|4]
```

You made the improper list by appending number instead of a proper list. (`[4]` is proper list `[4|[]]`.) See my [answer to *how is a list constructured by the erlang vm?*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31839473/49197) for more details how it works internally in BEAM VM.

Comment: Thanks! great help :]