# Using Erlang's NIF, How should I use malloc on ERL_NIF_TERM?

Tags: c, erlang, erlang-nif

I'm using Erlang's NIF, and the result of the C function is an array that I want to send back to erlang in the form of a list of tuples of three points, each is a tuple of two doubles.

to create this array currently I'm doing this:

```
ans = (ERL_NIF_TERM *)malloc(6*ntri*sizeof(ERL_NIF_TERM));

for (i=0;i<ntri;i++) {
    ans[i] = enif_make_tuple3(env,
            enif_make_tuple2(env,enif_make_double(env,x1[i]),enif_make_double(env,y1[i])),
            enif_make_tuple2(env,enif_make_double(env,x2[i]),enif_make_double(env,y2[i])),
            enif_make_tuple2(env,enif_make_double(env,x3[i]),enif_make_double(env,y3[i]))
    );
}
```

So far, it seems to work. but is it correct?
My reasoning was that on every cell of the array `ans` I have 6 doubles each with a size of `ERL_NIF_TERM`, so I allocate according to this.

But is it true?

Should I count the tuples?

What is the size of `ERL_NIF_TERM` anyway? 
Would double inside `ERL_NIF_TERM` be the same size of an int inside `ERL_NIF_TERM`? a tuple of 2 ints is also an `ERL_NIF_TERM`, is it the same size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, your double values and 2,3-tuples are allocated on the heap. It is accessed by the `env` variable. So you have to allocate only space for `ntri` `ERL_NIF_TERM`s which you store. They are a result of your `enif_make_tuple3` call. You also should use `enif_alloc` for allocation instead of `malloc` whenever you can (in your own code). Sou your code should look like:

```
ERL_NIF_TERM *ans = enif_alloc(ntri*sizeof(ERL_NIF_TERM));
if(!ans) return enif_raise_exception(env, enif_make_atom(env, "insufficient_memory"));
// use enif_make_badarg(env) prior to R18

for (i=0;i<ntri;i++) {
    ans[i] = enif_make_tuple3(env,
            enif_make_tuple2(env,enif_make_double(env,x1[i]),enif_make_double(env,y1[i])),
            enif_make_tuple2(env,enif_make_double(env,x2[i]),enif_make_double(env,y2[i])),
            enif_make_tuple2(env,enif_make_double(env,x3[i]),enif_make_double(env,y3[i]))
    );
}

ERL_NIF_TERM result = enif_make_list_from_array(env, ans, ntri);
enif_free(ans);
return result;
```

Now about second question, *What is the size of `ERL_NIF_TERM` anyway?* The size of `ERL_NIF_TERM` is a word on your platform. It is 8B on 64b and 4B on 32b or 64b halfword one. It can be stored in the stack or register so you don't have to allocate required memory and you can pass it as a simple parameter to the functions.

**Edit**: You don't have to allocate memory at all. It is more efficient to construct result list directly.

```
ERL_NIF_TERM result = enif_make_list(env, 0);

for (i = ntri; i;) {
    i--;
    result = enif_make_list_cell(env,
        enif_make_tuple3(env,
            enif_make_tuple2(env,enif_make_double(env,x1[i]),enif_make_double(env,y1[i])),
            enif_make_tuple2(env,enif_make_double(env,x2[i]),enif_make_double(env,y2[i])),
            enif_make_tuple2(env,enif_make_double(env,x3[i]),enif_make_double(env,y3[i]))
        ),
        result
    );
}

return result;
```

Comment: Ok, than I can think of it more like some kind of pointer to the real location on the heap, thats all makes more sense now.

Comment: @Deddy: It actually is [tagged pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31839473/49197)